# Looping return from AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have following code returning value from AsyncStorage

```
const getData = async () => {
        try {
            let listlayana = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('layanan'));
            return listlayana
        }catch (e){

        }
    }
    const datas = getData()
```

and i trying to loop this function result with this

```
{
                datas.map((item, i) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={i}>
                        <View key={i} style={styles.listitem}>
                            <Text style={styles.listtext} >{item.nmlayanan}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.listtext, {color: "#b4b3b3"}]}> > </Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ))
            }
```

and i got this following error

```
undefined is not a function (near '...datas.map...')
```

Comment: The call to AsyncStorage is asynchronous. The element rendering doesn't wait for it. So, till the AsyncStorage gets the datas, it will show as undefined. You have to render the elements in if condition.

Comment: and also it should be `const datas = await getData()`

Comment: Looks like getData returns an async function. `const datas = await getData()` should do the trick. However What I would do is look at making `datas` part of the component state and updating it once you have received a result from `getData`

Comment: cant use await if not in async function

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.useEffect and React.useState for this target like this:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState(); //add this useState for the data

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    let listlayana = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("layanan"));
    return listlayana;
  } catch (e) {}
};
  
// and add this async useeffect for fetching data from asyncstorage
React.useEffect(async () => {
  const scopeData = await getData();
  setData(scopeData);
}, []);
```

and then your render function like this:

```
{data.map((item, i) => (
  <TouchableOpacity key={i}>
    <View key={i} style={styles.listitem}>
      <Text style={styles.listtext}>{item.nmlayanan}</Text>
      <Text style={[styles.listtext, { color: "#b4b3b3" }]}> > </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

and your component like this:

```
export default function SOF() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      let listlayana = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("layanan"));
      return listlayana;
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const scopeData = await getData();
    setData(scopeData);
  });

  return (
    <View>
      {data.map((item, i) => (
        <TouchableOpacity key={i}>
          <View key={i} style={styles.listitem}>
            <Text style={styles.listtext}>{item.nmlayanan}</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.listtext, { color: "#b4b3b3" }]}> > </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: `React.useState()` only can used inside function, and `render()` must be inside `class`, how can i do that, sorry im still newbie

Comment: Post edited my bro!